# Build error "com.android.tools.r8.internal.k2: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O"

Tags: guice, tensorflow-lite, android-r8, methodhandle

I have a module within my app that depends on `org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.15.0` library. This library in turn depends on `com.google.inject:guice:5.1.0` which is the source of the build error.

Below is an excerpt from the *Build Output*

```
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.tools.r8.internal.k2: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\saeed\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.google.inject\\guice\\5.1.0\\da25056c694c54ba16e78e4fc35f17fc60f0d1b4\\guice-5.1.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform guice-5.1.0.jar (com.google.inject:guice:5.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\saeed\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.inject\guice\5.1.0\da25056c694c54ba16e78e4fc35f17fc60f0d1b4\guice-5.1.0.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

What's baffling to me is that the error showed up about 2 weeks ago after the code has been building fine for almost a year now and no changes have been made to it during this period. Even when I go back to an old commit which I know, for sure works. This build error shows up.

The easiest solution, which is mentioned in the build output, is to increase the minSdk to 26. This is not a desirable solution for me as some of my users are below api level 26.I'd like to avoid going this route as much as possible.

Also, when I set minifyEnable to true, the build is successful but doing that breaks some other parts of the app. I've been searching for a way to set minifyEnable to true for just that module but so far, haven't been successful.

Comment: Which version of AGP are you using? It was downgraded to a warning some time ago (https://r8-review.googlesource.com/69902). This change to the compiler should be in AGP version 7.4 and later.

Comment: @sgjesse
I upgraded AGP to 7.4.2, from 7.3.0, and it builds fine now but there's another issue; I'm depending on the module as a library in another project and the error shows up there. That library is on  AGP 8.0.1.